# How do you change a global variable in elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

```
package-archives
(("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/") ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))

setq package-archives '(("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
```

But then when I evaluate `package-archives` again, I get the original value:

```
package-archives
(("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/") ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some parans, I can't tell if it's just a benign typo, but it would cause your issue. The correct for is `(setq VARIABLE VALUE)`

Comment: As @jozefg said, add parens around `setq...`: `(setq...)`. And remove the `) (`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add parens:

`(setq package-archives '(("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))`